# PHP throwing E_DEPRECATED even though disabled via error_reporting

Tags: php

I recently upgraded to PHP 8.1 and did my best to fix instances of where NULL was being passed to built-in functions such as `trim()` or `strtolower()`.  As expected, I missed some.  However, it seems that the exceptions thrown by this in PHP are not E_DEPRECATED.  I can't find what type of exception is documented to be thrown exactly.  The migration guide just says the below and the comment in the code makes me think it would throw E_DEPRECATED.

> Scalar types for built-in functions are nullable by default, this behaviour is deprecated to align with the behaviour of user-defined functions, where scalar types need to be marked as nullable explicitly.

I have error_reporting in my php.ini set to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` and yet I am still getting exceptions thrown.  I log the text of the exception in our database and it sure looks like a deprecation message.  Does anyone know what type of error is thrown exactly?

I have an error handler defined but am not passing anything in the second parameter for the error levels.  Maybe I am misunderstanding how set_error_handler works in conjunction with error_reporting?

Comment: There is no single example of such stacktrace. Why not just upgrade the code instead?

Comment: Obviously, fixing the code is ideal.  But a deprecation typically isn't something that would break the way the code functions.  Only shows that something is deprecated.  My app shows a generic Page Error page when the error handler detects any errors.  So the user is unable to use the page if a deprecation error is thrown.  I don't believe that's how it used to work.  Its a bad user experience for something that shouldn't technically break the code.